# Filter/WHERE using timestamp

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to create a filter to see anything happening during a certain period of time of day using my `datetime` variable which has the date and time in format like this:

> 2009-07-30 16:05:15

How I can create a WHERE clause that will let me look at any entries where the timestamp of that variable is between certain hours such as 17:00:00 and 07:00:00 the following day.

Which Imagine would be two separate clauses starting

> > 17:00:00 OR < 07:00:00 respectively

Comment: the title of the question is misleading because op isn't filtering an actual tsql timestamp column but on a string column which happens to have a datetime format. But this isn't op's fault https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/202950/compare-timestamp-type-columns-in-sql-server

Answer (score 3):

Use `DATEPART` function

```
WHERE DATEPART(hh, [Date Column]) between 7 and 17
```

or

```
WHERE NOT DATEPART(hh, [Date Column]) between 7 and 17
```

for the night

Comment: If you added a `NOT` then this would be what the question was asking for.

Comment: Since only the hour is being checked this lumps together all times within the last hour, e.g. the first example should exclude `17:05:00`, but does not.

Answer (score 2):

Using the `datepart()` function works for your particular problem, because it is based on hours.  The more general solution is to deal with times.  For instance:

```
where cast(col as time) >= '17:00:00' and cast(col as time) < '17:30:00'
```

Answer (score 0):

you can filter like this:

`where time_field_name between first_value and last_value`

try this:

```
SELECT FORMAT(CAST(time_field_name  as datetime2(0)), N'HH:mm:ss')

 FROM time_table 

 where FORMAT(CAST(time_field_name  as datetime2(0)), N'HH:mm:ss') between '7:00:00' and '17:00:00'
```